Micromdm remote error: tls: error decrypting message
I am trying to set up MicroMDM with Docker and followed the instructions in the
https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm/blob/main/docs/user-guide/quickstart.md#generate-mdm-csr
Everything is working fine, but we are receiving the following error in the Docker logs:
Post "https://api.push.apple.com/.......": remote error: tls: error decrypting message.

Issue got fixed
